# Active State in Navbar not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is my navbar code, but the active state is not working. When I click the cart, it stays at the home, which was set as active in this HTML code. What is the problem here?

```
<html lang="en"><head>
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="bootstrap/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="home.php">company</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="home.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i><span>&nbsp;Home</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="all_categories.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i><span>&nbsp;Order</span></a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="register.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-registration-mark"></i><span>&nbsp;Register</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="login.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i><span>&nbsp;Login</span></a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You will have to assign your 'active' class to the <li> you want it to be applied to.

Comment: @MarioLopez does it mean should create a different navbar file for each page?
can't I have just one php file and the active state will change automatically once the other page is clicked?

Comment: Is it a single page or multiple pages?

Comment: user1023 as @KheemaPandey Pandey says it dependes if it is single or multiple pages. If it is single yes, you have to copy the navbar on each page.

Comment: @MarioLopez  what do you mean by single or multiple pages?

Comment: @KheemaPandey what do you mean by single or multiple pages?

Comment: It depends on if you are loading a new page on the browser or updating the content of the current one using Ajax. For the first option you have to copy the navbar, for the second option you can use javascript.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are using a single page. By using jquery `.addClass` and `.removeClass` you can activate the `li` which is clicked. Check the **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/zujokame/1/edit)** for clear picture.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $('ul.nav li a').click(function (e)
{
  $('ul.nav li.active').removeClass('active');
  $(this).parent('li').addClass('active');
});          
});
```

Comment: I tried to add this code, but it still didn't work in my code:(

Comment: if there are multiple pages then above code won't work because `active` class doesn't store locally. It will only if you have only Web page.